# sphinx: Including .tex file via raw:: latex

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, docstring

I want  to include latex doc in sphinx. sphinx html build does not include the latex file linked using `.. raw:: latex` directive. I have

this is my dir structure

```
docs/
    source/
        importlatex.rst
        index.rst

    build/
    tex/
       texfile.tex
```

`index.rst` looks like

```
Welcome to documentation!
=========================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   icnludelatex
   and-other-stuff
```

`icnludelatex.rst` looks like:

```
Include Latex
=============

.. raw:: latex
    :file: ../tex/texfile.tex
```

[this reference](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) gives example for including html

```
.. raw:: html
    :file: inclusion.html
```

why is this happening?

Comment: Sphinx didn't raise any errors for that inclusion. it creates a page with heading (i have this in separate .rst with heading)

Comment: `tex/` is outside the `source/` directory, so either move it inside or add it to your `conf.py` as an additional path for source files.

Comment: Suggest making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and push it to a public repo so I can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 8):

When you use a `raw` directive, the block is only interpreted by the *writer* associated. Example, `.. raw:: latex` works if you generate LaTeX but it is invisible to HTML.

What you need is a parser for LaTeX, but in a fast search, I only find parsers for markdown ([recommonmark](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) and jupyter notebook ([nbsphinx](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io)).

Maybe, a quick and dirty solution is to convert your latex doc to rst using pandoc (you may lose some formatted text).

```
pandoc -s texfile.tex -o texfile.rst
```

and then use the `include` directive in your `icnludelatex.rst`.

```
.. include:: texfile.rst
```

Comment: thanks, i have done this before but pandoc messes up equations, tabular etc so I was hoping to import latex directly would be a less of a hassle

Comment: @muon maybe you can convert first to html (using hevea, latexml or pdf2htmlex) and then use include html.